# Java log cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, lombok

I'm studying a spring project at eclipse IDE.

I met this error 'log cannot be resolved' at all of 'log.info( ... );'

[enter image description here][1]

and these are the solutions I found and worked on but didn't work.

1. check Eclipse or STS installation path is not in English
2. 'lombok.jar' reinstall
3. remove 'runtime' in the dependency of log4j in pom.xml
4. remove and reinstall '.m2' file folder
5. change '@log4j' to '@Slf4j'

I saw many posts about this problem, but I can't fix. Please help me.
and please let me know if I need to upload more code as this is my first time.
Thank you

code

```
..src/main/java/controller

    package org.zerock.controller;
    
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Date;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
    import org.zerock.domain.SampleDTO;
    import org.zerock.domain.SampleDTOList;
    import org.zerock.domain.TodoDTO;
    
    import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j;
    
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/sample/*")
    @Log4j
    public class SampleController {
    
       @InitBinder 
       public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
       SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
       binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
       }
    
       @RequestMapping("")   
       public void basic() {
    
          **log.info("basic...................");** 
    
       }
    
       @RequestMapping(value = "/basic", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
       public void basicGet() {  
    
          **log.info("basic get...................");**
    
       }
    
       @GetMapping("/basicOnlyGet")
       public void basicGet2() {
    
          **log.info("basic get only get...................");**
    
       }
    
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <!--  <scope>runtime</scope>-->
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.22</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocA0M.png
```

Comment: Have you configured Lombok to eclipse? Try to look at "How to configure project Lombok to eclipse?" chapter here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-project-lombok-in-java-and-how-to-get-started/

Comment: Really? That was the entire error message? No stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the log4j,org.slf4j dependencies and just add the lombok dependency and use @Slf4j as the annotation I don't think there will be an error

Answer (score 0):

Go to lombok jar in .m2 repository in CMD and execute the command java -jar lombok version.jar and new pop up will open for installation of the particular jar on eclipse path click on install. And then go to eclipse and clean and build the project.